# official laravel nginx config doesn't work for me

Tags: laravel, nginx

On my local machine doesn't work nginx config from [official laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/deployment)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /example.com/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

But it worked with changes in a few lines

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

changed to

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}
```

and everything works fine. Can anyone explane me the difference in that piece of code and is it unsecure ?

Answer (score 0):

Only reasonable diff I see inclusion of files: `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` and `fastcgi_params`

You issue could be fixed simply by adding:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
```

to `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params` file.

In old versions of nginx that line existed.
But from `1.10.x` it was removed and become reason of blank screen.